# Issue Configuring Spring Security and JWT

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have a project with microservices. I am trying to make an auth server that uses JWT. I am encountering problems. I am using springboot 2.7.10

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Deprecated
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

In the configure method the addFilter doesn't seem to Accept the JwtAuthorization and Authentication filters. Here is the Implementation for those two.

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;

        setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/services/controller/user/login");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException {
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));

        String body = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername() + " " + token;

        res.getWriter().write(body);
        res.getWriter().flush();
    }
}
```

I tried various filter from different guides but it still always gives me the same error. The problem is that I have another project that has the same code but it works there. Please help!

Comment: what error ? any stracktrace ?

Comment: @KenChan it saud that the addFikter methid accepts a filter. And it says that my JetAuthorizationFilter and JwatAuthenticationFilter are not filters.

Comment: you are aware that this type of authentication is not recommended by spring security and is considered insecure. That is why you have had to build all these custom filters. Stop following the tutorial that you are following JWT tokens should never be handed out to browsers of several security reasons. Read the spring security docs and implement FormLogin instead

Comment: @Toerktumlare can you please send me a direct link to the docs if you have it handy? Thanks.

Comment: i dont, i suggest you use google and go to the spring security website and start reading the official docs and reconsider your entire solution and instead start by doing more research. Also read up on why JWTs should not be used as sessions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong dependencies. I was using spring-security-config v5.7.x alongside spring security 6 and Springboot 3.1 which created this mess. I just had to update the spring-security-config to v6 for that to work.